# When performing a fast likelihood fit (flavio) why can we assume the uncertainties are weakly dependent on fit parameters?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

In the angular analysis of the $B^{0} \rightarrow K^{*}\mu^{+} \mu^{-}$, Wilson coefficients can be determined from experimental data of angular observables through the following (flavio - a python package) process:

1. Choose the Observables to provide to Flavio and specify the Wilson coefficients of interest
2. Flavio will then define a theoretical model relating the experimental observables to the Wilson coefficients specified.
3. Flavio will then use a FastLikelihood (instead of a Bayesian or Frequentist because its less computationally intensive) method to calculate a likelihood function for the given data, by integrating over experimental uncertainties and nuisance parameters.

Now, in order to use the FastLikelihood method, we need to assume three things:

1. The experimental observable values and uncertainties follow a Gaussian distribution
2. Ditto the theoretical observables
3. The covariances/uncertainties are weakly dependent on the fit parameters (I've seen this written in both ways).

Why is it justified to assume the final point (3) for this decay?

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you may want to try over at [stats.se]

Comment: Also, while you've introduced a numerical package as part of the post, this question isn't actually about [tag:computational-physics] (instead about statistics), so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score -1):

The [flavio docs](https://flav-io.github.io/docs/fits.html#fast-likelihood-approach) say "The last point is by far the strongest assumption and its validy [sic] has to be checked whenever the method is employed".

I interpret that to mean that we can’t assume it holds and we must check it numerically, rather than checked analytically by thinking about what we know about the decay(s) under consideration. Though it doesn't seem to offer any suggestion for how it would be checked. You could perform the 'slow' full calculations and see whether you obtained similar results, but that would destroy the advantage of the 'fast' method.

Comment: It seems to me the question is about the justification of the weak dependence of uncertainties & fit parameters, rather than the numerics/implementation of it.

Comment: That assumption could be justified if it was checked numerically or if we knew something about the decay formula and could figure it. My hunch is the code authors have in mind the former

Comment: I think you've completely misunderstood what I said.

Comment: Oh sorry. What did you mean?

Comment: OP is looking for a **reason why** the fit parameters & uncertainties ought to be weakly dependent (probably ideally independent)--with a potentially unnecessary caveat of "this [specific] decay". That is, they are looking for a physical and/or statistical answer, rather than the "its checked numerically" you've responded with

Comment: (and by itself, answering "it's checked numerically" particularly dumbfounds me, considering we're talking about *numerical software*. Of course it's checked numerically, that's how programs work!)

Comment: Indeed, we can’t understand each other. I can’t make sense of your remark in brackets. I was proposing the fast & approximate likelihood approach could be checked by comparing it to results that don’t make the approximation.

Comment: It looks to be plain english to me, so I'm not sure what the disconnect is, and I'm not sure how else I can say how you've missed the mark on answer. 